# Collect Emitted Values in a Sequence

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 observables `A` and `B` which can emit at any time. But only when `A` emits a new value and then `B` emits a new value too, I collect these 2 values. If `B` just emits new values without `A` emitting new values first, I don't collect any values.

I know `concatMap` might be useful but it needs the previous observable to complete whereas in my case neither ever completes until everything is destroyed.

Comment: What do you want to happen if A emits multiple times without any values arriving for B?

Comment: @MattBurnell Those values emitted by A will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be modelled as projecting each element of A into the first arriving element of B, discarding any previous subscription to B when a new A arrives, e.g.:

```js
A.pipe(
  switchMap(x => B.pipe(
    first(),
    map(y => ({ a: x, b: y }))
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried this before I submitted this question here. So with `switchMap`, after B emits for the first time, any successive emissions from A will be discarded, even though B can still emit after A. Eg. in the sequence of A -> A -> A-> A -> B -> A -> B, the last A will be discarded by `switchMap`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried this on rxjs 4 here: https://jsbin.com/fuqakehobi/edit?html,js,console. Apologies for the out-of-date library use. Is switchMap not equivalent to flatMapLatest in the version you're using?

Comment: Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69969073?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50) of this working in RxJS 7.

Comment: @MattBurnell That works! I will find out my version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BizzyBob That works too. Thanks so much!